# Move pie chart points by title?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through each point on a bar-of-pie graph and move specific points to the second plot, however, I can't seem to figure out how to reference the plot points by their title? Is this possible? Please find my code below.

```
Sub FixPieSlices()
Dim chtCombined As ChartObject, chtABC As ChartObject, chtXYZ As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set workbook and charts
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB")

With ws
    Set chtCombined = .ChartObjects("PieAll")
    Set chtABC = .ChartObjects("PieABC")
    Set chtXYZ = .ChartObjects("PieXYZ")
End With

With chtCombined.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    .Points(1).SecondaryPlot = 0
    .Points(2).SecondaryPlot = 0
    .Points(3).SecondaryPlot = 0
    For i = 4 To .Points.Count
        .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 1
    Next i
End With

With chtABC.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    .Points(1).SecondaryPlot = 0
    For i = 2 To .Points.Count
        .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 1
    Next i
End With

With chtXYZ.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    .Points(1).SecondaryPlot = 0
    .Points(2).SecondaryPlot = 0
    For i = 3 To .Points.Count
        .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 1
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: A screenshot of what you're trying to do would be helpful here.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, though I got it figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job finding the solution on your own :)

Just wanted to show you how you could shorten your code a bit

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    ' Reorganize slice/plots of pie charts on pivot table updates
    ' (changing of slicers triggers the macro)

    Dim chartNames As Variant
    chartNames = Array("PieAll", "PieABC", "PieXYZ")

    Dim j As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Loop through each chart, move slices not named 'Financial' to second plot
    'Then remove point explosion for all slices that aren't 'Other'
    For j = 0 To UBound(chartNames, 1)

         With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB").ChartObjects(chartNames(j)).Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
            For i = 1 To .Points.count
                If Not .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "*Financial*" Then
                    .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 1
                Else
                    .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 0
                End If

                If .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "Other*" Then
                    .Points(i).Explosion = 10
                Else
                    .Points(i).Explosion = 0
                End If
            Next i
        End With

    Next j

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This is much more concise; I've overwritten my previous code with it. Thanks for this, @Marcucciboy2!

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering and Googling, I've figured out how to make the change based on the slice name.

**Notes:**

1. The name field pulls in all name information. So, for example, if
   you've ticked 'percentage' on for each slice, that will also be
   pulled into the name-- "December Sales; 25%". This needs to be
   accounted for when looping through the name.
2. This macro is placed in the ThisWorkbook module. This allows it to
   trigger everytime a slicer / pivot table is changed.

Find the updated code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableUpdate(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)

' Reorganize slice/plots of pie charts on pivot table updates
' (changing of slicers triggers the macro)

Dim chtCombined As ChartObject, chtABC As ChartObject, chtXYZ As ChartObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set workbook and charts
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DB")

With ws
    Set chtCombined = .ChartObjects("PieAll")
    Set chtABC = .ChartObjects("PieABC")
    Set chtXYZ = .ChartObjects("PieXYZ")
End With

'Loop through each chart, move slices not named 'Financial' to second plot
'Then remove point explosion for all slices that aren't 'Other'
 With chtCombined.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    For i = 1 To .Points.Count
        If Not .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "*Financial*" Then
            .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 1
        Else
            .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 0
        End If

        If .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "Other*" Then
            .Points(i).Explosion = 10
        Else
            .Points(i).Explosion = 0
        End If
    Next i
End With

With chtABC.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    For i = 1 To .Points.Count
        If Not .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "*Financial*" Then
            .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 1
        Else
            .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 0
        End If

        If .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "Other*" Then
            .Points(i).Explosion = 10
        Else
            .Points(i).Explosion = 0
        End If
    Next i
End With

With chtXYZ.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1)
    For i = 1 To .Points.Count
        If Not .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "*Financial*" Then
            .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 1
        Else
            .Points(i).SecondaryPlot = 0
        End If

        If .Points(i).DataLabel.Caption Like "Other*" Then
            .Points(i).Explosion = 10
        Else
            .Points(i).Explosion = 0
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```